# Text Shadow in IE 11 not working

Tags: css

The text in this example of text-shadow doesn't display in IE 11, but does in FF & Chrome.

http://codepen.io/maxnguyen/pen/

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/css-textshadow) IE has had full support for text-shadow since IE 10. Is there a way to alter the CSS so it would work in IE11?

```
<div id="box">
  <p id="flashlight">
    <span id="flash">MAX</span>
    <span id="light">NGUYEN</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  overflow: hidden; /*FF fix*/
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Geneva, sans-serif;
  background: hsl(210, 30%, 0%) radial-gradient( hsl(210, 30%, 20%), hsl(210, 30%, 0%));
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}


/* box ------------------------------------------------------ */

#box {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* fixes flashing */
}


/* flashlight ------------------------------------------------------ */

#flashlight {
  color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0);
  perspective: 80px;
  outline: none;
}


/* flash ------------------------------------------------------ */

#flash {
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: #bbb 0 0 1px, #fff 0 -1px 2px, #fff 0 -3px 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0 30px 25px;
  transition: margin-left 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
}

#box:hover #flash {
   text-shadow: #111 0 0 1px, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0 1px 3px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: margin-left 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.75, 0, 1);
}


/* light ------------------------------------------------------ */

#light {
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: #111 0 0 1px, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0 1px 3px;
}

#box:hover #light {
  text-shadow: #fff 0 0 4px, #fcffbb 0 0 20px;
  transform: rotateY(-60deg);
  transition:         transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.75, 0, 1), text-shadow 0.1s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because IE wants you to have a base color on the text. You also use `text-shadow` to define the base color.

You can change this so you also define the `color` property.

```
#flash {
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: #bbb 0 0 1px, #fff 0 -1px 2px, #fff 0 -3px 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0 30px 25px;
  transition: margin-left 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
}
```

Changes to

```
#flash {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #bbb;
  text-shadow: #fff 0 -1px 2px, #fff 0 -3px 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0 30px 25px;
  transition: margin-left 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
}
```

Where your first `text-shadow` is now assigned to the `color` property.

**Why does this happen?**

Well i'm not certain if this happend in the previous versions of IE. However as you can see at the [MS text-shadow generator](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_text-shadow.htm) there is a property that is not supported by chrome and FF; **spread distance**. This might suggest that IE does not use the same methods as chrome and FF do. 
*However it seems logic to give a base color before give a shadow to something.*

**Addition notes**

I suggest to also let `-webkit-`  support everything. For example `transition` in chrome is only supported by `-webkit-transition`.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8wgb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

this a very tricky issue where you probabilly could not find any answer, if you open a simple html files to ie10 or ie11 this will show all your text-shadow but you intrigated apps does not support the text-shadow even it shows some error means red line under the text-shadow text.

You just need to change the meta tags for this...use these

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> // ie supports
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">// for responsive
```