# IE11 Cutting Off Elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a grid of blog/media posts (http://qli.quietrev.com/media/ and http://qli.quietrev.com/articles/blogs/) and in every browser but IE - specifically 11 - the grid elements are being cut in half for seemingly no reason.

[image]

I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary here, and when inspecting elements I don't see any overlap that would be causing it.

On the headings and paragraph tags, I've tried a number of things such as `width: 100%`, `display: block`, and `overflow: hidden;` to force them to span the width of the `li`.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. In your CSS you have this

```
html, html a {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
}
```

If you remove the `text-shadow` in that CSS your content will show again. It seems that the value 0.004 is not supported in IE `text-shadow` property because if you change it to 0.4 then your text will show correctly.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't seem to fix the issue. I changed it to `0.1` and the issue still persists.

Comment: @buschschwick does it show correctly if you remove that line altogether?

Comment: Take a look at this [SO question and answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803062/text-shadow-in-ie-11-not-working). It seems there are some issues with text-shadow in IE even tho [caniuse says its fully supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=text%20shadow).